# When openapp in browser first time, favicon returns 404 (node js, express)

Tags: node.js, express, favicon

So, when open browser first time i mean not tab - browser itself, my node js app returns 404 (favicon not found). When open app in new tab - it works pretty good.
I'm using `express` and `serve favicon`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [serve fevicon](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) module .

Comment: app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static('public/images/favicon.ico')); ,it also works just try on my code.